# Matlab spilt one txt file to several files

Tags: matlab, file-io, split

I have a .txt file like this,which is tab delimiter.

```
nr  Time    Lx  Ly  Lz  Rx  Ry  Rz  Mark
1   32874.4114  0.4 -0.2    0.7 0.2 0   -0.7    0
2   32874.4213  0.4 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.7    0
3   32874.4313  0.4 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.9    1
4   32874.4413  0.4 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.9    0
5   32874.4514  0.2 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.9    1
6   32874.4613  0.2 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.9    0
7   32874.4713  0.2 -0.2    0.4 0.2 0   -0.9    1
8   32874.4813  0.2 -0.2    0.7 0.2 0   -0.9    0
```

I want to use Matlab to code and to spilt this .txt into three separate .txt files according to the Mark (when detect `Mark = 1`, then spilt it into a new .txt file)

following is the code:

```
  function splitdata(filename)

thelist=find(filename(:,9)==1)
thelist=[1; thelist];
n=length(filename);
m=length(thelist)
for i=2:m
    out=zeros(thelist(i-1)-thelist(i),9);
    out=filename(thelist(i-1):thelist(i)-1,:);
    thename=['output' num2str(i-1,'%03i') '.txt']
    dlmwrite(thename,out,'\t');
end
if thelist(m)<n
    out=filename(thelist(m):n,:);
    thename=['output' num2str(m,'%03i') '.txt']
    dlmwrite(thename,out,'\t');
end
```

The problem is: in the output file, the time column , the number after the decimal point is missing... anyone got some ideas how to keep the number after the decimal point?

Comment: You can start by reading the documentation of these functions: `fopen`, `regexp` and `str2double`.

Comment: the way I see it, you have two questions here: how to read read/write data, and how to split the matrix into multiple smaller ones according to the "mark". You should show us what you have tried so far, and which part you're having trouble with..

Comment: Use `textread` to read in the characters using the `\t` delimiter. After, use `Mark` to find which rows you need then perhaps use `arrayfun` to separate out the corresponding rows.  After, use `fopen` and `fwrite` to write out your new files.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution below should do the trick (at least it does for the simplified version you put above.

```
fi = fopen('myFile.txt','r');
fileCount = 1;
fo = fopen(['output',num2str(fileCount),'.txt'],'w');
header = fgets(fi);
fprintf(fo,header);
tline = header;
first = true;
mark_index = 8;
while ischar(tline)
    if (~first)
        values = cell2mat(textscan(tline,'%f '));
        if values(mark_index) == 1
           fclose(fo);
           fileCount = fileCount+1;
           fo = fopen(['output',num2str(fileCount),'.txt'],'w');
           fprintf(fo,header);
        end
        fprintf(fo,tline);
        tline = fgets(fi);

    else
        first = false;
        tline = fgets(fi);
    end
end

fclose(fo);
fclose(fi);
```

It will read the original file line by line, and look for a mark, if it sees the mark being set to 1, it creates a new output file and closes off the old one. This will keep repeating until there are not more files in the original document.

It will also place the same "header" into all create output files.

Comment: when i tried to use for example 'dat=dlmread('output2.txt','\t')' there's a problem "Mismatch between file and format string." The original file was tab delimiter, however, after split, it's not anymore.

Comment: @user3737929 The loops do not edit the lines at all, so if they were previously tab delimited, they should remain so.